Adding dynamic tabs to a tab control
I have the following code
This should add tabs to a tab control... the problem is that Im unable to see the changes if I edit the font size of the panel size, etc.
Also is there a way to see or edit using the visual designer things that are dynamic? I know its hard because its not static, but since the object is declared I was wondering if there is a way to set or see properties using it instead of going through tens of properties depending on how many objects you are creating. What am I missing?
Thanks in advance !
private void AddDynamicTabs()
{
    List<Zonas> ZonasList = Database.GetZonasFromDatabase();
    Console.WriteLine("CANTIDAD DE ZONAS " + ZonasList.Count);

    TAB_ZONAS.TabPages.Clear();
    // Calculate tab width based on the width of Panel_mesas and number of zones
    int tabWidth = Panel_mesas.Width / ZonasList.Count;


    for (int i = 0; i < ZonasList.Count; i++)
    {
        Zonas zonas = ZonasList[i];

        // Create a new tab page
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(zonas.NOMBRE);
        tabPage.Name = $"tabPage_{zonas.NOMBRE}";
        tabPage1.Text = $"tabPage_{ zonas.NOMBRE}";

        // Set properties for the tab page
        tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        tabPage.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        tabPage.Font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
        tabPage.Padding = new Padding(10); // Padding around the content of the tab page
        tabPage.Margin = new Padding(5); // Margin around the entire tab page
        tabPage.Enabled = true; // Enable or disable the tab page
        tabPage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true; // Use the default visual style for the tab page
        tabPage.AutoScroll = false; // Enable auto-scrolling for the tab page content
        tabPage.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No; // Set the text direction for right-to-left languages
        tabPage.Tag = null; // Set an object that contains data about the tab page
        tabPage.ToolTipText = "Tooltip for the tab page"; // Set a tooltip for the tab page
        tabPage.Width = 1000;
        tabPage.Height = 4100;

        // Optionally, set other properties
        // Example:
        // tabPage.BackgroundImage = yourImage;
        // tabPage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

        // Add the tab page to the TAB_ZONAS TabControl
        TAB_ZONAS.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

    }
}


Are you using Forms or Windows Forms?  I think you are using forms.  A tabPage is a control and you can use Find to get the children controls.  I do not like using Find because it is slow.  Normally issue like this is due to adding controls directly to a parent control.  Auto Sizing doesn't work well.  Solution is to add a Panel to the TabPage control and then add the child controls to the panel.  A Panel the Auto Sizing  will work while with a TabPage the Auto Sizing does not work.

Can you point me in the right direction? A Sample code or something?
I also noticed I was creating a tab instead of using the previously correct one ... I will post the corrected code

Try Panel panel = new Panel();  tabPage.Controls.Add(panel).  Then replace in your code tabPage with panel.

This code works:
private void AddDynamicTabs()
{
    List<Zonas> ZonasList = Database.GetZonasFromDatabase();

    // Create TabControl
    TAB_ZONAS = new TabControl(); // Assign TAB_ZONAS here
    TAB_ZONAS.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1112, 961);
    TAB_ZONAS.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    TAB_ZONAS.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;

    // Calculate and set ItemSize based on ZonasList count
    int tabWidth = TAB_ZONAS.Width / ZonasList.Count;
    TAB_ZONAS.ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(tabWidth - 10, 150);

    TAB_ZONAS.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(654, 12);
    TAB_ZONAS.Name = "TAB_ZONAS";
    TAB_ZONAS.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // Add TabPages dynamically based on the list of zones
    foreach (Zonas zonas in ZonasList)
    {
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(zonas.NOMBRE)
        {
            ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText,
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 79),
            Name = zonas.NOMBRE, // Unique name for each tab page
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1104, 878),
            Text = zonas.NOMBRE, // Set the tab text to the name from the list
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        };

        TAB_ZONAS.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
    }

    // Add the TabControl to the form
    this.Controls.Add(TAB_ZONAS);
}

